# Error Restarting Nginx : unknown log format "payload" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:57

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

1.Im trying to copy some files from a server then transfer it into other server using nginx. Before I make configurations, nginx can ran smoothly.
I can download the files which are:

`sites-available nginx.conf`

2. The script that I ran is:

`cp /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.bak
cp ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.bak
cp ./sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

systemctl restart nginx
`

3. all the cp lines are executed but the restart nginx line did not. I got error:
   `Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" for details.`
4. Then I went to /var/log/nginx/error.log to see the error which is:
   `unknown log format "payload" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:57`
5. the default file line 57 is "access_log /var/.....:

`location / { # First attempt to serve request as file, then # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404. # try_files $uri $uri/ =404; proxy_pass "http://<ip_address>"; proxy_http_version 1.1; proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade"; proxy_set_header Host $host; access_log /var/log/nginx/payload.log payload; }`
6. I replace  with my respective ip address. So Im stucked now and dont know how to go from here.
p/s: Please ask me again if Im not clear with my question, Im still a beginner in nginx-related stuff